# Updating Optionsmenu issue

Tags: python-2.7

I have following code and need it to update the same dropdownlist with new values. Currently it just creates a new list to the right of the existing one. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

```
import os
import sys
import Tkinter as tk

def edit():
var.set('Choose build')
choices =['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten']

option = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *choices)
option.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=20)

root.mainloop()

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar(root)
var.set('Choose build')
option = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, '')

root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (500, 150, 200, 150))
root.title("QCT Multimedia Build Metrics")

button = tk.Button(root, text="Edit Config", command=edit)
button.pack(side='left', padx=20, pady=10)

choices = ['one','two','three','four','five']

option = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *choices)
option.pack(side='left', padx=10, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what is var? Fix your formatting also.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method myself - I pass a new list to the updateOptions() method

```
def updateOptions(self,optionList=[]):
    option.set('')
    option['menu'].delete(0, 'end') # Delete old options

    for choice in optionList:   
        option['menu'].add_command(label=choice, command=tk._setit(var, choice)) 
    var.set(optionList[0]) # Set default value to be the first in the list
```